# bytes manipulation in 2'complement format using python

Tags: java, python, binary, offset

I have loads of 14 bits signed binary(sealed in 16bits) in 2'complement gathered those data from a sensor via BLE(bluetooth low energy). and I want to convert it to decimal.

I found a snippet code in **JAVA** which can parser the 14-bits binary in right order. but I am new to coding python. could you explain what is c[offset+1] and c[offset] & 0xFF? and how it could express in python?

```
private static Integer shortSignedAtOffset(byte[] c, int offset) {
    Integer lowerByte = (int) c[offset] & 0xFF; 
    Integer upperByte = (int) c[offset+1]; // // Interpret MSB as signed
    return (upperByte << 8) + lowerByte;
}
```

for example: 
a = 0010 1000 0000 0000
is that right if I say a+1 equal c[offset+1]? what is offset doing in binary, espcially related to sensors? 
thanks a lot
pls do answer me. really need help.

Comment: hi pros, do me a fever. if you don't want answer it, pls let other help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decode a 2'complement numbers in hex to decimal from a device. it has to consider 3 step before write a code.

1. what is input format? string or integer?
2. how many bits in output? how many bits need to be convert? for example, a  14 bits data sealed in 16 bits output. so it has to shift 2 bits[maybe right or left] before calculation.
3. what kind of data-endian in your output,either big endian or little endian? if output comes as [0:7],[8:15], it'd better to change the position it to [15,14,13.....,2,1,0]. then do the shift,then calculation the value.

the below code represent hex string to decimal

```
    def twocompbinstr(valstr, bits):
        if type(valstr) is str:
            valstr = int(valstr, 16)  #expect hex in string format
        if (valstr & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0:
            valstr = valstr - (1 << bits)
        return valstr
```

test code:

```
    h = '3aff' # 0011 1010 1111 1111
    # 14bits 2'complement integer is sealed in 16bit format.
    e = twocompbinstr(h,14)
    print e, type(e)

    output:
    -1281 <type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is wrong, `offset` is an array index.

Say `a=0x2A01`, this is how `a` is stored in memory:

```
a = 0010 1000 0000 0001
```

If we treat `a` as a byte array (`byte []`), denoted by `c`:

```
c[0] = 0x2
c[1] = 0xA
c[2] = 0x0
c[3] = 0x1
```

Then you can manipulate the bytes individually and later pack them back to an integer.
The conversion of integer to byte array (and vice versa) varies in languages.
Post a different question if you encounter problem.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I am still confused. so what offset is doing here? lowerByte = (int) c[offset] & 0xFF; is it find a special place to do the "&" job? so it will come like this: c[1] & 0xFF? and why it comes why two FF(a byte)?  but what ever, this snippets of Java is not correct.